# Node.js Async Series not working in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequence

I am trying to perform 2 loops in series, 1 before the other using the Async Node.js module.

```
async.series([
    insertSkill,//first loop
    insertBehaviours//second loop
], function(err, results){
        console.log(results);//print results
    });
```

This is the code in each function, I have removed some code for better readability

```
function insertSkill(fnCallback){
    async.eachSeries(Object.keys(behaviours), function (aSkill, callback){
        if (aSkill.indexOf('skillid') > -1) {
            if (behaviours[aSkill] == null || behaviours[aSkill] == "") {}

            connection.get().query('SELECT skill_id FROM skills WHERE skill_id = ?', num, function (err, skillResults) {

                if (skillTitle != null || skillTitle != "") {

                    connection.get().query('INSERT INTO skills SET ?', [skill], function (err, skillResults) {

                        if (err) {}   
                     else {
                            console.log("1");//PRINTING AFTER 2, DONT WANT THAT!!!                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        callback(null);
    },fnCallback);
}
```

Second Function

```
//Second Function
function insertBehaviours(fnCallback){
    async.eachSeries(Object.keys(behaviours), function (aBehaviour, secondCallback) {
        if (aBehaviour.indexOf('behaviourid') > -1) {
            if (behaviours[aBehaviour] == null || behaviours[aBehaviour] == "") {
            console.log("2");//PRINTING BEFORE 1, DONT WANT THAT!!!

                });
            }
        }
        secondCallback(null);
    },fnCallback);
}
```

The issue is, the second function insertBehaviours is happening first before insertSkills. I want insertSkills to happen first and before insertBehaviours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your first function, `insertSkill` has a couple of asynchronous methods in it. However, you're calling the callback on the iterator before those methods have chance to complete. Your `insertSkill` method should look more like this:

```
function insertSkill(fnCallback){
    async.eachSeries(Object.keys(behaviours), function (aSkill, callback){
        if (aSkill.indexOf('skillid') > -1) {
            if (behaviours[aSkill] == null || behaviours[aSkill] == "") {}

            connection.get().query('SELECT skill_id FROM skills WHERE skill_id = ?', num, function (err, skillResults) {

                if (skillTitle != null || skillTitle != "") {

                    connection.get().query('INSERT INTO skills SET ?', [skill], function (err, skillResults) {

                        if (err) {}   
                     else {
                            console.log("1");//PRINTING AFTER 2, DONT WANT THAT!!!                         
                            callback(null); // notice I moved this.
                          }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },fnCallback);
}
```

As that will only call the `callback` function once your two SQL statements have run.

Comment: Thank you so much mrwillihog, this fixed my issue!